# Eloquent models - How do i break this dependancy

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, eloquent, laravel-5

Take the following:

```
<?php


class EqUserRepository implements IUserRepository
{
    //...
    public function GetUserByID( $id )
    {
        return User::find( $id );
    }

}
```

You can see that it returns a `User`

`User` is extending `Model` (Which extends `Eloquent`)

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    public function Profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne( "Profile" );
    }
```

Now imagine in our controller, we inject our concrete implementation via the interface:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct( \App\Models\Contracts\Repositories\IUserRepository $userRepo )
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepo;
```

**All good so far!**

Now we have a controller method that calls upon our injected repository and gets a User returned...

```
public function GetDetails( $id )
{
        $user = $this->userRepository->GetUserByID( $id );
        return view( 'user', array( "Model" => $user ) );
}
```

Now in our view we call upon the profile:

```
<p> Name: <?= $Model->Profile()->first_name ?> </p>
```

**Oops, now our view is dependant on Eloquent because the `Profile` method on `User` is making calls using Eloquent.**

I have been trying to figure out the best solution to break this dependancy.

1. I thought that having my repository map data into a User class that did not extend Eloquent was a good idea... but then you have some looping to map the classes which is a bit of a waste of time... especially considering you could just as easily use `mysql_fetch_object( $query, "User" )` and have it map straight away.
2. So taking 1 into account, i thought the `DB` class must have a way of mapping direct to a type...
3. Have the User depend upon my `IUserRepository`, then my `Profile` function could look like this and that would certainly break the dependency, in a really good way!

.

```
public function Profile()
{
    return $this->userRepository->GetProfileByUserID( $this->id );
}
```

But you ofcourse cannot DI into an eloquent model. I tried using the boot overriding method, but that doesn't like DI too, of course...

**So, question time:**

1. Can you set the return type of the DB class?
2. Can you somehow DI on an eloquent model?

Comment: You might find that ditching Eloquent and using Doctrine fits better your purposes out of the box. From what I gathered using Eloquent, you simply cannot separate the model from the data access. In your example though, you might use $Model->Profile->first_name if I'm not mistaken, which is a little less dependant if we might call it so.

Comment: I have, I've now moved to Doctrine, it's much better! You get full typeahead, getters and setters are almost forced upon you... allowing for stricter select column definitions, no database queries inside the model... ah the wonder.

Comment: Would you like to put this as the answer? It's a reasonable solution!